# Possibility to create Rails Standalone App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I did a small Rails-App. Is there a chance to convert it to a standalone version, so that you can run it without installing rails, running the server etc.?

**Edit:**
Sorry, the question came short. I want to pack the whole thing "as it is" with all gems, into one executable.

Comment: are you looking to extract the functionality into a gem to be included in other applications?

Comment: See the edit I just did.

Answer (score 3):

No installation of Ruby, no installation of RubyGems, no installation of the various gems, no installation of SQLite; There's only one executable!

You can create the standalone Executable with `RubyScript2Exe`.

**RubyScript2Exe** transforms your Ruby script into a standalone, compressed Windows, Linux or Mac OS X (Darwin) executable.

See the complete steps with details [here](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/distributingrubyapplications/rails.html).

Comment: One more question here: If this works, can I then call the app via my browser on 'http://localhost:3000/'?

Comment: offcourse yes, that executable will start the server and you can browse then.

Comment: Problem is: When I do the changes suggested in this tutorial... My application won´t work anymore...

Comment: sorry to ask, can I convert Rails app to exe?

Comment: Did you get any working solution for the same? I also want convert rails application to exe. Please let me know if you have done this already. Thanks